# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror

There is an error when I execute This code-
**for i in len(str_list):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

How would I fix it? (Python 3)

```
def str_avg(str):
    str_list=str.split()
    str_sum=0
    for i in len(str_list):
        str_sum += len(str_list[i])
    return str_sum/i
```

Comment: `len(str_list)` will give a integer, you can only iterate through the `iterals`. May be you want `range(len(str_list))`.

Comment: Why not just use `for elem in str_list:` and `str_sum += len(elem)`? Python `for` loops are *for each* constructs, so you can loop directly over the lit of elements.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to loop over in integer; `len()` returns one.

If you must produce a loop over a sequence of integers, use a [`range()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

```
for i in range(len(str_list)):
    # ...
```

By passing in the `len(str_list)` result to `range()`, you get a sequence from zero to the length of `str_list`, minus one (as the end value is not included).

Note that now your `i` value will be the **incorrect** value to use to calculate an average, because it is **one smaller** than the actual list length! You want to divide by `len(str_list)`:

```
return str_sum / len(str_list)
```

However, there is **no need** to do this in Python. You loop over the elements of the *list itself*. That removes the need to create an index first:

```
for elem in str_list
    str_sum += len(elem)

return str_sum / len(str_list)
```

All this can be expressed in one line with the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), by the way:

```
def str_avg(s):
    str_list = s.split()
    return sum(len(w) for w in str_list) / len(str_list)
```

I replaced the name `str` with `s`; better not mask the built-in type name, that could lead to confusing errors later on.

Answer (score 2):

For loops requires multiple items to iterate through like a list of [1, 2, 3] (contains 3 items/elements).

The len function returns a single item which is an integer of the length of the object you have given it as a parameter.

To have something iterate as many times as the length of an object you can provide the len functions result to a range function. This creates an iterable allowing you to iterate as any times as the length of the object you wanted.

So do something like

```
for i in range(len(str_list)):
```

unless you want to go through the list and not the length of the list. You can then just iterate with

```
for i in str_list:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def str_avg(str):
    str_list = str.split()
    str_sum = len(''.join(str_list))  # get the total number of characters in str
    str_count = len(str_list)  # get the total words

    return (str_sum / str_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

While running for loop we need to provide any iterable object. If we use `len(str_list)` then it will be an integer value. We can not make an integer iterable.

Solution - Using `range()` function.

```
for i in range(len(str_list)):
```

Get complete detail in this article. [enter link description here](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable-fix/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).